# is_dir and is_file not working with path from root

Tags: php, web, filesystems

im using scandir() to check a directories files ,it works correctly with path from root like /dir1/dir2/.... (the dir1 isn't behind my .php file its a folder in root )

but when using is_dir and is_file  on the same path it outputs false result

how can I fix this?

Comment: How about the permissions for that file?

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
function getDirContents($dir) {
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    if (!$handle) return array();
    $contents = array();
    while $entry = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($entry=='.' || $entry=='..') continue;

        $entry = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$entry;
        if (is_file($entry)) {
            $contents[] = $entry;
        } else if (is_dir($entry)) {  
            $contents = array_merge($contents, getDirContents($entry));
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    return $contents;
}

$directoryPath = 'Path to folder';
$getDirContents = getDirContents($directoryPath);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(getDirContents );
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Why should OP try your answer without knowing what it does? A _good answer_ should accompany __some explanation__

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at PHPs own [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.directoryiterator.php) object, which is faster and more detailed than the single functions.

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        var_dump($fileinfo->getFilename());
    }
}
```

This piece of code is directly taken out of the documentation. It takes the current directory of the currently executed file and iterates through it. As long as the current $fileinfo isn 't a dot it dumps the filename of the files and subdirs in this directory.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "path example"?